# Is there a way to specify the last connecting punctuation/word of the authors list in apacite?

Tags: bibtex, punctuation, apa-style

How can I make apacite use a different connecting punctuation/word between the last 2 authors (in both the article body and bibliography)?

Instead of "Johnson, J. B., & Smith, J. (2013). Title of the article...", do "Johnson, J. B., 和 Smith, J. (2013). Title of the article...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apacite.sty` defines, and `apacite.bst` uses, the following macros for that:

```
\newcommand{\BBAA}{\&}  % between authors in parentheses and ref. sec.
\newcommand{\BBAB}{and} % between authors in text
\newcommand{\BBA}{\BBAA}
```

So do a

```
\renewcommand{\BBA}{\BBAB}
```

in your preamble after loading `apacite.sty`.

If you use a language file like english.apc (loaded automatically depending on the document language), these commands get redefined again when `\begin{document}` is issued. In this case,

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}%
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work for me as is though. `english.apc` also has a `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{\&}` and for whatever reason loads after my `\renewcommand`. However, making a local copy of `english.apc` (there isn't a Chinese one or apc of any Asian language) and then modifying the macros there does solve the problem.